# How to check Windows session from a web page?

Tags: javascript, c#, windows, internet-explorer, bho

I want my web page to perform an action every time the user Locks (Logoff) or Unlocks (Logon) the Windows session. If I'm able to recurrently call a JS code that checks the session status and do something based on the result, that would work too.

I got the first option to work with C#:

```
SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += new SessionSwitchEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionSwitch);

static void SystemEvents_SessionSwitch(object sender, SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Reason == SessionSwitchReason.SessionLock)
   {
      // Do something
   {
}
```

Unfortunately, through this method I'm only able to perform an action on my C# program and not on a web page.

Any idea of how I could achieve one of the following?

- Trigger a JS function within a specific web page from the C# program above.
- Check the Windows session from the web page itself.

EDIT: Please note I'm talking about the Windows (OS) session, not the browser window session.

Comment: incorrectly tagged as java

Comment: As you tagged that question with `bho`, I assume you target Internet Explorer (11). If so, I think your only path is to call JS in the page from your C# program. Search for that in StackOverflow, instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a Windows Service which registers the Windows session in a file, then I am reading the file from the web page. Problem solved.